# Why is not the value of an input set by javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

The html part is a create view for products. So the user is able to add as many lines of products as it wants. The html part is the button to add a line and the div with the id thtat is supposed to keep the creation form of the product.
The javascript part is the code that add a html part when the button is clicked, and the part that gets the value, get access to the database and get another data and displays it in another input.

So, the code is supposed to:

1. get the value (which is id of the product the user is interested) from the select[name="product[]"];
2. find this product in database and show its unit price in the input[name="unitinput"].

The code is below. Why is it wrong and how it can be done?
The Class Product is passed to the view through the method in ProductController. Before I tried to use @foreach in the script, but it didn't work out.

How can I set a value of another input based in the selected option using javascript and getting data from database? Or is there another way to do this? I put a question mark in this part because I that part was wrong according to the comments of this question.

```js
// add new line
  $("#add").click(function(){
    idModNova = autoInc(idModNova);

    var input ='<div id="product-'+idModNova+'"><select class="form-control" id="Product" id_mod_nova='+idModNova+' name="product[]" required><option disabled selected>Select product</option>@foreach($products as $product)<option value="{{$product->id}}">{{$product->name}}</option>@endforeach</select></div>';
    
    input += '<div form-group" id="unit-'+idModNova+'"><div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">$</span></div><input name="unitinput" type="number" step=".01" class="form-control value" id="unitinput" id_mod_nova='+idModNova+' value="0.00" readonly></div></div>';

    $("#form").append(input);
    return false;
  });

  // TRYING TO GET AND SET THE VALUE      
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#Product').attr('id_mod_nova').change(function() {
        var valorselect = $(this).val();
        if (valorselect == "?") {
          $('#unitinput').attr('id_mod_nova').val("?");

        }
      });
  });
```

```html
<div class="row" id="form"></div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="add" style="margin-bottom: 32px">Add New Line</button>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: @foreach(??? Is that some sort of templating code in the middle of your javascript? Seems odd.

Comment: Please replace that server-side template code with final JS so we can actually check/fix the code. Edit: `$('#Produto'.attr('id_mod_nova'))` isn't valid jQuery, you would need `$('#Produto').attr('id_mod_nova')`. However this will attempt to read the value of attribute `id_mod_nova`, then attempt to assign a change listener to the *value*. That's not how it works.

Comment: @epascarello `@foreach` is a Laravel Blade templating instruction. Perfectly normal for Laravel users to use... but probably not inside JS.

Answer (score -1):

- `@foreach` is mangling server (or other) template rendering code with your JS - it will never behave as you expect.  If you're rendering from client-js, pass a JS object or JSON directly.
- `$("#adicionar").click` is declared before your ready function and depending on load order may well not even be there to bind against

Overall, it seems you are confusing server and client code in a way that isn't how it works.  You don't want to mingle the two in the way that you have.